# remove dot at end of text

Tags: c#, .net, string

i have to remove the dot at the end of text howt to i do

usign c#, dot.net

example       =          abc.

i want this       =    abc

Comment: will the undesirable dot always be the last character?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
string a = "abc.";
string b = a.TrimEnd('.');
```

Answer (score 11):

You can remove any dots at the end of a string using the `TrimEnd` method:

```
str = str.TrimEnd('.');
```

You can use the `Substring` method to remove only the last character:

```
str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
```

If the last character should only be removed if it's a period, you can check for that first:

```
if (str[str.Length - 1] == '.') {
  str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
}
```